# How to get substring from string?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the last word from the string:

```js
var str =  "Member/GetRefills";
var param = str.split(" ").pop();
console.log(param);
```

Expected result:

```
GetRefills
```

Comment: Try splitting on `"/"` instead.

Comment: well what do you expect when you split on a whitespace???

Comment: And pop() removes the last entry from an array. So if you split on '/' and then pop() you will actually get "Member" and not "GetRefills".

Comment: @NawedKhan stick the following in your browser console.  That is not correct.  "Member/GetRefills".split('/').pop()

Comment: I haven't downvoted, though the avoidance of `pop` in favor of effectively writing what pop does, is odd.

Comment: This is interesting @Taplar . By definition the pop() removes the last entry from an array. var a = ["hello","world"]; a.pop(); here a will be "hello". But instead if we assign the result of pop to a variable it stores the popped (last) value as in var a=["hello","world"].pop(); here a will be "world".

Comment: True, the array will only be the remaining elements without the last element.  That is a different statment than saying pop() returns the first element, which is inaccurate.  Which, referring to your statement you didn't not explicitly say that.  However without context "you will actually get" can be inferred as that possibly against what you meant.

Comment: @Taplar But getting the last element of an array by pop() is not a good practice in my opinion since the full array might be needed later on. (not in this case)

Comment: @Taplar I didn't say pop() returns the first element. Based on documentation pop() removes the last element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop and https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp

Comment: @NawedKhan read your first statement again.  It can be easily read that you are saying the result will be "Member" and not "GetRefills".  It is unclear what result you are referring to, be it the result of the array, or the result of the pop call.  It's ambiguous.

Comment: @EvikGhazarian that's entirely a contextual issue.  If they do not care if the array is modified, pop works.  I would have less of an issue if both solutions were presented in an answer, and the merits of both explained.

Comment: I get it now @Taplar. "The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns that element" I based my comment only on the first part of this definition and not the returning part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try splitting on `"/"` instead.

```js
const str = "Member/GetRefills";
const param = str.split("/").pop();
```

Comment: pop() removes the last entry from an array. So you will actually get "Member" and not "GetRefills"

Comment: @NawedKhan nope.

Comment: I take that back. "The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns that element" so if you read the returned value it will be "GetRefills". However if you read the array now it will be one element less (not the case here, so never mind)

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
var param = str.split('/');
var paramLast = param[param.length - 1];
```

> pop() is not always a good practice. pop() removes the last element of
>   an array which in some cases might cause problems.
>
> `param[param.length - 1]` does the same job as pop() but more safely.

Comment: This assumes a single slash, which works in this specific case but would fail for 'Member/Bob/GerRefills'. Hence `pop` instead of `[1]`.

Comment: I was actually updating the answer